# Simplify boolean expression: (a + b)(b'+ c)(a + c) = (a + b)(b'+ c)

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-expression

Hello I am trying to simplify this expression (proving consensus expression):

```
(a + b)(b'+ c)(a + c) = (a + b)(b'+ c)
```

I was thinking of adding `(a+b)(b'+ c)(a + c + b' + b)`, but I don't know what to do after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this:

```
  (a + b)(b' + c)(a + c)
= (ab' + 0 + ac + bc)(a + c)
= (ab' + ab'c +ac + ac + abc + bc)
= (ab' + ab'c + ac + abc + bc)
= (ab'(1+c) + ac + bc(a + 1))
= (ab' + ac + bc)
= (ab' + c(a+b))
= (ab' + bb' + c (a+b))
= (a+b)(b' + c)
```

The key step is realising that `bb'` = 0 so you can safely add that term without affecting the result in the penultimate step.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me get the final answer! I was able to follow all the steps

Comment: @user3792518 No problem. Remember to mark the answer as accepted, so that anyone viewing it knows that the question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

(A+C')(B'+C')

AB'+AC'+BC'+C'

AB'+(A+B+1)C'

We Know ( 1+anything =1)
So required expression AB'+C' .